# Shower head not working with hot water

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I have a 3 knob tub, hot, cold, and in the middle the diverter. When I turn the diverter knob the cold water comes out of the shower head but the hot water continues to come out the tub as if I never turned the diverter. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: did this start all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your diverter is the issue. It may not be turning completely. To test, turn o,my hot on then switch the diverter back and forth. Still no shower, then the diverter is not turning completely. Or it could be blocked. Either way, pull the diverter out and take a look.